# Automatically bound histogram regions?

Tags: function-construction, regions, distributions

Given a histogram of some data, such as e.g. in the following sample

> https://www.codepile.net/pile/NLlNgP60

```
sample = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/yFJa87Hn", "RawJSON"];
```

I can make a histogram:

```
Histogram[sample, 100]
```

> [image]

I am looking for ways to automatically find bounds on the histogram distributions, such as I manually added in the following picture:

> [image]

Note that the bounds are a bit fuzzy, strictly outside the distribution when the edge is sharp and high, but reaching a bit inside the distribution when the falloff has a soft "tail".

Can this be done in Mathematica? What would be a good approach?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the data collection process and what a penalty occurs when an area of low density is missed?  I ask because otherwise this becomes a subject-matter-free data manipulation where the "answer" can be "I'll know it when I see it."  The two current answers below certainly do well at the heavy-lifting part of sorting out potential groups.  I'm curious as to what you do with the potential suspects once they're in the line up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option could be to use [`FindClusters`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindClusters.html) and [`MinMax`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinMax.html) or [`Quantile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantile.html)

```
sample = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/yFJa87Hn", "RawJSON"];

clusterEdges = MinMax /@ FindClusters[sample, 3]
(* {{1.00194, 1.0076}, {0.988321, 0.994815}, {0.995332, 1.00138}} *)

clusterEdges2 = Quantile[#, {0.1, 0.9}] & /@ FindClusters[sample, 3]
(* {{1.00319, 1.00651}, {0.989299, 0.994465}, {0.997048, 
  0.999483}} *)


Histogram[
 sample
 , 100
 , Epilog -> {
   Thick,
    Black, Map[ Line[Transpose[{#, {10, 10}}]] &, clusterEdges],
    Red, Map[ Line[Transpose[{#, {15, 15}}]] &, clusterEdges2]
   }
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since you're working with pretty dense histogram data you can also play with the smooth-kernel density estimator form of your histogram:

```
SmoothHistogram[sample]
```

[image]

```
dist = SmoothKernelDistribution[sample];
cddd = PDF[dist, x];
boundary1 = FindMinimum[{cddd, x > .995, x < 1}, {x, .995}] // Quiet
boundary2 = FindMinimum[{cddd, x > 1, x < 1.005}, {x, 1}] // Quiet

{23.8826, {x -> 0.995819}}

{18.3624, {x -> 1.00092}}
```

You can also play with the density estimator to find a more precise cut-point:

```
SmoothHistogram[sample, .0002]
```

[image]

```
dist2 = SmoothKernelDistribution[sample, .0002];
cddd2 = PDF[dist2, x];
boundary12 = FindMinimum[{cddd2, x > .995, x < 1}, {x, .995}] // Quiet
boundary12 = FindMinimum[{cddd2, x > 1, x < 1.005}, {x, 1}] // Quiet

{2.54235, {x -> 0.995272}}

{0.352377, {x -> 1.00102}}
```

If you know a good way to get `FindMinimum` to return all the minima within a given range that'll work better than plot-and-guess starting conditions